# connect to server api page

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch

ther by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). to terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the cli flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see [

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../modles/User");


router.get("/register", async (req,res) => {
   
    const user = await new User({
    username:"jhon",
       email:"jhon@gmail.com",
       password:"123456",
    
    
   })

   await user.save()
   res.send("ok")
   
});

module.exports = router;
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLgqa.jpg) (rejection id: 1) (node:13400) [dep0018] deprecationwarning: unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. in the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: wrap the code inside the route handler function in `try-catch` block. Also, you don't need to `await` the `new User(....)`. The `await` is only needed before `user.save()`

Answer (score 0):

you only need a await and a catch. The first one is useless because you initialize your class.

So do that :

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../modles/User");


router.get("/register", async (req,res) => {
   
    const user = new User({
    username:"jhon",
       email:"jhon@gmail.com",
       password:"123456",
   })

   await user.save().catch(e => e) // Return the errors in the void. You can console.log it.
   res.send("ok")
   
});

module.exports = router;
```